# Formatting a date field to just show the date, not minutes.

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

A date field in a report returns the date value as:

2015-07-01 13:30:27.000

Is there any way I can script this to appear as:

01 July 2015 (or 01-07-2015 or 01/07/2015)  - basically to cut out the hours, minutes and seconds?

The best I have managed is: CONVERT (varchar(17),DATE,113) AS Date1 but this still leaves me with:

01 July 2015 13:30

Any expertise in solving this would be very welcome. I can tidy it up in SSRS, but would love to script it instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work `Format(<datefield>,"dd-MMM-yyyy")` in the report, or if you want the SQL to return something you don't have to format, just take the `Left(<dte-str>,11)` if your `<dte-str>` is the format I have above

Comment: Thanks for getting back Seeds: both methods work fine.